# Product topology, projection mappings & compactness

Tags: general-topology

I have some doubts concerning *projection* mappings and product topologies.

The definition states that given an indexed family of topological spaces $\{ (X_i , \tau_i )_{i \in I} \}$, we can set $X = \prod_{i \in I} X_i $. Hence, $\tau = \prod_{i \in I} \tau_i $ is the ***product topology*** on $X$, if every projection mapping $\pi_i : X \to X_i$ is continuous for every $X_i$.

In order to make sense of it, I simply think about the standard topological definition of continuity, i.e. for every $i \in I$, and for every open (resp. *closed*) $G \subseteq X_i$, the preimage $f^{-1} (G) \subseteq X$ is open (resp. *closed*).

**Questions:**

1. *Does a projection mapping that induces the product topology on a family of TS preserve compactness?*
   In other words, is the case that for every $i \in I$, and for every *compact* $G \subseteq X_i$, the preimage $f^{-1} (G) \subseteq X$ is *compact*?
2. *If it is so, does the property extends to any continuous function, beyond the projection mapping in the product topology case?*

Any feedback is more than welcome.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Consider the product of a circle $S^1$ with the real line $\mathbb{R}$, and look at the projection map onto the circle. Doesn't that give a counter-example?

Comment: @mathmandan: Thanks a lot for the comment. May I ask you to be more explicit (maybe with an answer, I will be happy to accept)? Indeed, I am not completely sure I completely see the counterexample, because I don't really see why the subset of $S^1$ is *not* compact. Indeed, if we take $[0,1] \in \mathbb{R}$, that induces two "sublines" on $S^1$, but I don't see why they are not compact.

Comment: Sudden thought: Are they not compact because they are ***disconnected***? *(I know it can all sound trivial to you, but my basics really fail from time to time)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the topology $\prod_i\tau_i$ is not the product topology, but the so-called *box topology*. They only coincide if the familly is *finite*. The true product topology is generated by products of open sets $U_i\in\tau_i$ (up to here, this is the box topology), but those open sets must be *$U_i=X_i$ except for finitely many $i$'s*.

Second, the product topology makes all projections continuous, but this does not characterize it. The property that characterizes it is that a mapping $\ f:Y\to\prod_iX_i$ is continuous if and only if all components $f_i=\pi_i\circ f$ are continuous (note the *if and only if*).

Next, concerning the questions about inverse images of compact sets, this is essentially related to the notion of *proper map*. In absolute generality proper means *universally closed,* that is the mapping is closed and any extension $f\times$Id${}_Y$ is closed too (look at wiki, for instance). However technical this is, under mild restrictions this is equivalent to what you asked for: *inverse images of compact sets are compact*. Now given $\pi_i:X_i\times Y_i\to X_i$ (denote $Y_i=\prod_{j\ne i}X_j$) and $K\subset X_i$ compact, $\pi_i^{-1}(K)=K\times Y_i$ is compact if and only if (Thychonoff) $Y_i$ is compact, if and only (Tych again) if all $X_j$ are compact. Thus projections are proper if and only if all factors of the product are compact.

Finally suppose the factors $X_i$ compact and also *Hausdorff*. Consider any continuous mapping $f:X\to X_i$. Then any compact set $K\subset X_i$ is closed (by the Hausdorff assumption), hence $f^{-1}(K)$ is closed in $X$, which is compact (Tych once again). But closed in compact is compact, hence $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact. (This is just the general argument to show that a continuous mapping from a compact space to a Haussdorf one is proper.)

Comment: +1 to your straight to the point answer. Thus, summing up, *proper* mappings preserve compactness, right? (Thanks a lot for all the other details!)

Comment: Right, proper maps preserve compactness __by inverse image.__

Answer (score 2):

Please see the answer of Jesus RS, which includes useful information about the product topology and its relationship to the box topology in general.  My answer here is just a requested clarification of an example I suggested as a comment.

Let $X_1$ be the real line $\mathbb{R}$ and $X_2 = S^1$ (under the usual Euclidean metrics).  Explicitly, $S^1 = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : \lvert z \rvert = 1\}$. Then let $X = \mathbb{R} \times S^1$ be their Cartesian product, endowed with the product topology (equivalent to the box topology since it's a product of finitely-many spaces, specifically just two spaces).

You can visualize $X$ as a "long cylinder" in 3-dimensional Euclidean space.

Now let $G = \{ 1 \}$ be the subset of $S^1$ that has only a single element, namely the complex number $1 = 1+0i$.  Then $G$ is compact (why?), and we look at the projection $\pi_2 : X \to S^1$.  The preimage of $G$ under this map is certainly $\mathbb{R} \times G = \mathbb{R} \times \{ 1 \}$, which turns out (under the topology induced as a subspace of the product space $X$) to be homeomorphic to the real line $\mathbb{R}$--see next paragraph if you're not sure about this.

Sketch of proof that $\mathbb{R} \times \{ 1 \}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$: First, the inclusion $\mathbb{R}\times \{ 1 \} \to \mathbb{R} \times S^1$ is continuous (inclusions are always continuous--why?), and you told us that the projection map $\mathbb{R} \times S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, so their composition is a continuous map $f: \mathbb{R}\times \{1 \} \to \mathbb{R}$.  This function $f$ is actually quite simple; it's $f(x, 1) = x$.  To show that $f$ is a homeomorphism, we'd need to show that $f$ is a bijection (which should now be very simple) and show that $f^{-1}$ is also continuous.  This last part basically just requires us to show that for any open set $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}\times \{ 1\}$, the set $f(V)= \{ x : (x,1) \in V \}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. $\Box$

But the real line is not compact (show by using the definition of "compact", or recall that compact means closed and *bounded* in Euclidean space), so you have a counterexample: the preimage of a compact subspace under a projection need not be compact.

Note: it shouldn't be surprising that $\mathbb{R} \times \{ 1 \}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$; indeed it would be shocking if it were anything else.  Further, it shouldn't matter if we consider $\mathbb{R} \times \{ 1 \}$ to be a subspace of $\mathbb{R} \times S^1$ or as a product  space in its own right...and indeed it doesn't matter at all.

In fact in this example, the circle $S^1$ was irrelevant; you could get the same thing by taking $X_2$ itself to be a single-point space and $G = X_2$, and $X_1$ to be any non-compact space.

This might also be a good time to mention that not all open sets $U$ in the product space $X=X_1 \times X_2$ will be of the form $U_1 \times U_2$ where $U_i$ is open in $X_i$, because you have to also accept any *union* of such products as open sets.  (Think about open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ and open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.)  Rather, such products $U_1 \times U_2$ form what is called a *basis* for the box topology.  It wasn't quite clear from your question if you had noticed this or not, so I thought I'd throw it in.

Further info:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_topology

[Why are box topology and product topology different on infinite products of topological spaces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871610/why-are-box-topology-and-product-topology-different-on-infinite-products-of-topo)

[Product and Box Topologies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72176/product-and-box-topologies)

Comment: +1. Thanks a lot. Regarding your original comment, when I read $S^1$, I think about a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Hence, I think about *two* possible projections that map to $\mathbb{R}$. That's why if we take, as I wrote, $[0, 1] \in \mathbb{R}$ we get a disconnected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that corresponds to some "sub"-lines of the original circle. Does what I have written make sense? *That's how I actually saw your comment*.

Comment: Moreover, now I don't see another thing regarding your comment. Basing on Jesus' answer, compactness is preserved by continuous projections. Thus, how can your comment constitute a counterexample? Any clarification is much appreciated! :)

Comment: Regarding your latest comment: a projection may take a non-compact set to a compact set (as in the case of projecting $\mathbb{R}\times \{1 \} \to \{ 1\}$.  What it can't do is take a compact set to a non-compact set. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Image_of_Compact_Space_is_Compact

Comment: Regarding your prior comment, $S^1$ is *not* the product of two copies of $[0,1]$, as you well know, so while it makes sense to project it onto either the $x$-axis or the $y$-axis, that isn't a projection from a product space.  When I said "the product of $\mathbb{R}$ with $S^1$, I really meant $\mathbb{R} \times S^1$, which you may visualize as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Just for the sake of fairness, I accepted Jesus questions because it was the first that came, and it was fairly complete in addressing my basic doubts, but again thanks a lot for all the info.

Comment: Just one additional comment. Of course, I did not claim that $S^1 = [0,1]^2$. What I thought is that $S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, and then $\pi_1 : S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$. Thus, $\pi^{-1} ([0,1])$ should actually be well-defined, and I don't see why it should not be *compact*.